# React Native Flatlist Category Filter

Tags: reactjs, react-native

The following code displays a list of posts from an API inside of a FlatList. The FlatList works and displays all my posts but I am trying to filter the posts based on category through a Picker that uses the filterCrime state.

Here is my current which displays posts and has the picker that sets filterCrime state properly.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      loading: true,
      data: [],
      page: 1,
      refreshing: false,
      filterCrime: ''
    };
  }

fetchData = () => {
    const { page } = this.state;
    const url = 'MyAPI';
    this.setState({ loading: true });
    fetch(url)
      .then(res => { 
        return res.json()
      })
      .then(res => {
        const arrayData = [...this.state.data, ...res]
        this.setState({
          data: page === 1 ? res : arrayData,
          loading: false
        });
      })
  };

   updateFilter = (filterCrime) => {
      this.setState({ filterCrime: filterCrime })
   }

componentDidMount() {

      this.fetchData();
  }

   handleLoadMore = () => {
    this.setState(
      {
        page: this.state.page + 1
      },
      () => {
        this.fetchData();
      }
    );
  }; 

  render() {
    return (
  <Container>

<Picker selectedValue = {this.state.filterCrime} onValueChange = {this.updateFilter}>

               <Picker.Item label = "Disorder" value = "24" />
               <Picker.Item label = "Assault" value = "23" />
               <Picker.Item label = "Theft" value = "21" />
</Picker>

//This properly shows category slug that was selected from Picker //
<Text>{this.state.filterCrime}</Text>

     <FlatList
        data={this.state.data}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id} 
        renderItem={({ item }) =>{      
          return (
<Tile>
  <View>
    <Title>{item.title}</Title>
    <View>
//This displays the posts category//
      <Caption>{item.categories[0]}</Caption>
    </View>
  </View>
</Tile>
          )
        }}  
        onEndReached={this.handleLoadMore}
        onEndReachedThreshold={0}
      />

</Container>
    );
  }
```

Here is my attempted code trying to filter the Flatlist based on the filterCrime value, but nothing happens, it still loads all posts regardless of the category.

```
<FlatList
        data={this.state.data}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id} 
        renderItem={({ item }) =>{

          //My Attempt trying to filter posts that does not work// 
          if ( !this.state.filterCrime || item.categories[0] == this.state.filterCrime ) {      

          return (
<Tile>
  <View>
    <Title>{item.title}</Title>
    <View>
//This displays the posts category//
      <Caption>{item.categories[0]}</Caption>
    </View>
  </View>
</Tile>
          )
        }}} 
        onEndReached={this.handleLoadMore}
        onEndReachedThreshold={0}
      />
```

**If I manually set the filterCrime state as filterCrime: '23' and reload app, the newsfeed correctly filters and will only show posts with the category slug of 23, so my API works and this is possible, the only problem is doing it with the Flatlist on Picker change.**

Answer (score 0):

To re-render `Flatlist`, you will need to set `extraData` props to it.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html

> By passing extraData={selected} to FlatList we make sure FlatList itself will re-render when the state changes. Without setting this prop, FlatList would not know it needs to re-render any items because it is a PureComponent and the prop comparison will not show any changes.

So for your case will be setting `this.state.filterCrime` to it

```
<Flatlist
    extraData={this.state.filterCrime}
    ....
/>
```

Alternatively, you may filter your `this.state.data` instead of filter in the `renderItem`